# what import statements do I need to use with redux-promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How do I setup the redux-promise middleware, specifically what import and configurations statements do I need?

https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise

The readme states `import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise'`, and I'm assuming I have to import createAction as well.. but is that all I need, or do I need to configure or add it to the redux configuration somehow?

Is this all I need to do?

actions/SampleActions.js

```
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';
import { WebAPI } from '../utils/WebAPI';

export const getThing = createAction('GET_THING', WebAPI.getThing);
export const createThing = createAction('POST_THING', WebAPI.createThing);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware needs to be applied when you create your store. The Usage section of the redux-logger readme presents example code that applies redux-promise (amongst others). https://github.com/fcomb/redux-logger

Comment: so I should apply the middleware in the app.js or client.js rather than in the actions file?

Comment: Yes. Wherever you use createStore.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add it to your root component file, the file where you created your Redux store, although on npmjs.com it tells you to import

`import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';`

You can just as well import it like so:

`import reduxPromise from 'redux-promise';`

The important thing is that the `'redux-promise'` part is consistent as its how it can be identified inside your `node_modules` directory.

So wherever you have your Redux store set up, it would look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import reducers from "reducers";

export default ({ children, initialState = {} }) => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, applyMiddleware(reduxPromise));

  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
};
```